# Pandas Join- Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes, `telemetry` and `errors1`. I am doing pandas join operation on these two dataframes.

The telemetry dataframe looks like this

[image]

and the `errors1` dataframe looks like this

[image]

Now the join operation is done like this

```
error_count= telemetry.join(errors1, on= ((telemetry['machineID'] == errors1['machineID']) 
                               & (telemetry['datetime'] == errors1['datetime'])), 
                            how='left')
```

which is giving the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-222-84983d093331> in <module>
----> 1 error_count= telemetry.join(errors1, on= ((telemetry['machineID'] == errors1['machineID']) 
      2                                & (telemetry['datetime'] == errors1['datetime'])), 
      3                             how='left')

/anaconda/envs/azureml_44cb7df5d7402b6a151767e96abfe35d/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py in new_method(self, other)
     62         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     63 
---> 64         return method(self, other)
     65 
     66     return new_method

/anaconda/envs/azureml_44cb7df5d7402b6a151767e96abfe35d/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in wrapper(self, other)
    519 
    520         if isinstance(other, ABCSeries) and not self._indexed_same(other):
--> 521             raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
    522 
    523         lvalues = extract_array(self, extract_numpy=True)

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Comment: This should work `telemetry.join(errors1.set_index(('machineID','datetime')), on=['machineID', 'datetime'], how='left')` join operation does the join on index, if you want to do it on columns use `pd.merge`

Comment: @darthbaba it is giving this error `KeyError: "None of [('machineID', 'datetime')] are in the columns"`

Comment: it is actually `errors1.set_index(['machineID','datetime'])` pass in a list not a tuple

Comment: Not working, I have edited the question with the new error. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use `pd.merge`

`df = pd.merge(telemetry, errors1,  how='left', left_on=['machineID','datetime'], right_on = ['machineID','datetime'])`

Comment: Same error coming- `ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
`

Comment: is datetime column in both dataframes of datetime64[ns] dtype? I suggest you to convert both columns to same type use pd.to_datetime, one of the datetime column is of object type

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Now merge is done but as you can see in question `Errors1` dataframe I have integer values. But after merge, it all got to `NaN`. Any guesses why?

Comment: Do you understand how left join works? if indexes that are present in left dataframe but are not preset in right dataframe those rows will be having NaNs. If you don't want NaNs use `how='inner'` while merging

Comment: Thanks, worked. Can you please upvote the question?